# Enter Not Working in document.getElementById.value

Tags: javascript, html

right now i m using `\n` to enter line break

```
document.getElementById('inputarea').value = "<h1>\nHead\n</h1>";
```

i want to write code as

```
document.getElementById('inputarea').value = "
<h1>
Head
</h1>";
```

but its not working. I m displaying value in text area.

suggest any way to display code without using \n or br.

Answer (score 2):

Use HTML Backtick (`) instead

Check the snippet

```js
document.getElementById('inputarea').value = `<h1>
Head
</h1>`;
```

```html
<textarea id="inputarea"></textarea>
```

Comment: but i want show it in same format i dont want to use any tag

Comment: check the snippet.

Comment: @user7791084 it was a mistake. corrected. Check it now

Comment: Thank You So Much. So Nice of You. Its really helpful